# Sum of Squares of List Elements

Tags: python, list, iteration, computer-science

Write a function sum_of_squares(xs) that computes the sum of the squares of the numbers in the list xs. For example, `sum_of_squares([2, 3, 4])` should return 4+9+16 which is `29`:

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should try and narrow down your question to a specific one. Please visit [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. With the format of your question, this will for sure be closed.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: While the answers below are perfectly correct, I would suggest you not look at them, but rather try to explain what difficulties you have. "help" does not mean having someone do it for you.

Comment: Check out [the last page, question 16](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/f11/chapter7.pdf)

Comment: @Amadan As a teacher, I agree with you. You're not helping somebody learn when you just write a solution to their assignment for them.

Comment: I'm sorry this is the first time I am using this website. I will post up my own version of the code next time before asking a question! Sorry!

Comment: I think that homework related questions should be flagged. The student would benefit by learning how to code than by getting ready solutions to his problems. Nothing personal against you Nate:).

Comment: @Nikolas, I don't believe that they should be flagged, or closed in such a rush, as a group. I do agree with you when the question is asking the community to just crunch out code though. I am not a monkey.

Comment: @Nikolas: There was [an extensive discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on Meta about homework. Homework questions are *not* discouraged. However, a) the question needs to be posted properly, not as a copy-paste (show own effort, provide all relevant data...), b) the answer should help the asker (as I said before, code dump will only help the student in the short term). This question was closed because it failed on due diligence, not because it was about homework.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a nice one-liner

```
sum_of_squares = lambda L : sum(map(lambda iGotThisFromStackOverflow:iGotThisFromStackOverflow**2, L))
```

Comment: Cheeky ;) I hope they submit this as their answer for the assignment!